# Why the output has different column order on different runs?

Tags: r, random

I have a piece of code in R. Every time I run it on a cluster, I get an answer where the order of columns are different. (It seems to be OK on my laptop). If I order the column so they have the same order, answers are identical, the only problem is ordering of the columns.

```
NNs_loc_year <- Reduce(cbind, 
                      split(NNs_loc_year, 
                            rep(1:n_neighbors, each=(nrow(NNs_loc_year)/n_neighbors)))) %>%
               data.table()

# rename columns 
NN_dist <- NN_dist %>% data.table()
names(NN_dist) <- paste0("NN_", c(1:n_neighbors))
names(NNs_loc_year) <- paste0(names(NNs_loc_year), paste0("_NN_", rep(1:n_neighbors, each=2)))

NN_chi <- pchi(as.vector(NN_list$nn.dist), PCs)

NN_sigma <- qchi(NN_chi, 1)

NN_sigma_df = Reduce(cbind, 
                      split(NN_sigma, 
                            rep(1:n_neighbors, each=(length(NN_sigma)/n_neighbors)))) %>%
               data.table()

names(NN_sigma_df) <- paste0("sigma_NN_", c(1:n_neighbors))

NN_dist_tb = rbind(NN_dist_tb, NN_dist)
NNs_loc_year_tb =  rbind(NNs_loc_year_tb, NNs_loc_year)
NN_sigma_tb =  rbind(NN_sigma_tb, NN_sigma_df)}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that suggests parallel computing. Could it be that you've parallelised column-wise operations which you column-bind? In that case, you might end up with different column orders depending on which compute node finishes first.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits. I do not know, I have no knowledge of parallelising!
This is the part of code that I am suspicious about!

I really have no idea. If the code is parallelised, why it does not happen on the laptop?

Comment: @MauritsEvers That could not be the case, I request for one node on the cluster!

Comment: *"Every time I run it on a cluster"* I'm confused. *You* mentioned running it on a cluster. So are you not using multiple (compute) nodes for parallelisation? If not, what does *"run[ning] it on a cluster"* mean and how is that relevant?

Comment: I am confused as well! Cluster is a set of CPUs, memories, like a normal computer, that I run the code on.

But I do not do parallel computing.

It is relevant, because it does not happen on my computer, that is weird to me!

I run the code, with the same input, twice, both times, answers are identical on the laptop, but different order of columns on the cluster.

Do you think cluster is equivalent to parallel computing?

Comment: Well this will be difficult (impossible?) to debug without reproducible code and sample data. Can you try to reduce the issue to a minimal code example? The key thing here is to ensure that others can re-run your example by copy&paste-ing your code into an R terminal.

Comment: *"Do you think cluster is equivalent to parallel computing?"* I'd say that a compute cluster is commonly used for its parallel computing and parallel data processing capabilities. Cluster computing usually deals with process parallelisation; if you just want a fast(er) (high-mem) computer, why not use a single workstation?

Comment: Perhaps cluster is mainly used for parallel computing. But that is not my issue right now. I do not know what work station is, I can use the cluster, so I do it. 
(for 80 hours, but I want to carry my laptop, so I use the cluster.)

I wish there was a way to share data here! Let me what I can do!

Well, the data are not huge in this case, but I am afraid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190606/discussion-between-no-lie-and-maurits-evers).